# type casting gtkmm window to gtkmm container

Tags: gtkmm

How can i type cast gtkmm window object to gtkmm container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to - `Gtk::Window` inherits from `Gtk::Container`, so you can use any container method on a window.

Answer (score 3):

Some functions in gtkmm do not return an object, but a pointer. So, you have to use RefPtr (https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-refptr-casting.html.en).

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Container> contaier_var =
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Window>::cast_dynamic(window_var);
```